# running veins on my own example is not working

Tags: omnet++, veins

i am working in VANET. the veins, sumo and omnetpp interconnection worked for me as veins tutorial. but when i try to replace erlangen(veins exmple by my own  map.osm of sumo results ( map.launchd.xml,map.net.xml,map.osm,map.poly.xml, map.rou.xml, map.sumo.cfg, trips.trips.xml and typemap.xml) and change omnetpp.ini file erlangen to map it results Simulation terminated with exit code: 133 and run#0:finished with error. i am using all latest versions please help me with the problem

Comment: Please read how to ask on this site and format your post: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [Veins FAQ](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/faq/):

> **What happened? My simulation crashed.**
>
> Simulations using Veins run three programs in parallel: OMNeT++ runs the network simulation, SUMO runs the road traffic simulation,
>   and sumo-launchd acts as a proxy between both. Consequently, the first
>   step should be finding out which program crashed.
>
> Debug output for sumo-launchd can be found on the console, as well as in its log file. Please refer to its --verbose and --logfile
>   parameters for controlling how much (and where) information is
>   written.
>
> Debug output for SUMO (both stdout and stderr) is captured by sumo-launchd and stored in its log files (see above).
>
> Finally, debug output for OMNeT++ can be found on the console (immediately before the "simulation terminated" line). You can get
>   more in-depth information by enabling debug-on-errors and running the
>   simulation with a debugger attached (see below).
>
> [image: Location of error message in OMNeT++ IDE console]